# Jenkins. Create property file before executing pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using Jenkins pipeline, before executing a script (Jenkinsfile) it is needed to create a file in the job's directory - prop.properties

It could have following content (Content of the file should be specified in the Job configuration, on UI):

```
URL=https://app.example.com
TIMEOUT=6000
```

Could you please advice, how to do it?

**Possible questions:**

Why it could not be done in pipeline script? - Because properties should be specified from UI.

Why it is needed to create a file instead of running build script with specific parameters ? - Because it could from 1 to 20 properties. For each job different properties would be specified.

Why it is needed to create a file instead of using operating system’s environment variables? - Because, on one machine different jobs could be running at the same time and properties for each job is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what job parameters are for. In the job configuration (through the UI), you can specify different parameters and their types:

[image: Jenkins job parameters]

or in your Jenkinsfile itself like so (in which case they'll be added to the job config after the first build):

```
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'URL',
            description: 'The URL to target.'
        )
        string(
            name: "TIMEOUT",
            description: 'How long to wait for the "foo" operation to time out.'
        )
    }
```

Then, when the user fires up a build through the Jenkins UI, they're prompted to provide these params before building. If you expect the builds to be started automatically (e.g. by a GitHub hook), be sure to provide default values as well.

Then, in your Jenkinsfile, you can use them like so:

```
sh "foo --timeout ${TIMEOUT}"
```

or

```
sh "foo --timeout ${params.TIMEOUT}"
```

And they're not shared between different builds, even on the same machine.

Comment: There is a file with defaults settings (parameters) inside a project, there are a lot of settings (parameters) inside this file.

And through Jenkins job, I would like to override default settings (parameters), so for one Jenkins job it could be - URL, TIMEOUT, for another job - 10 absolutely different parameters.

By using approach that you mentioned, for all Jenkins jobs it's needed to specify the same parameters, but values could be different.

Comment: So in Jenkinsfile should be something like this:
`sh "./gradlew clean ui-test:test -DURL=${URL} -D TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT}"`

And it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Artur: If you're trying to provide piles of different config parameters for the _same_ job, you can just take the union of them and provide defaults. Or consider breaking it apart into two separate jobs. Also, for the parameter usage syntax, it depends on your Jenkins version - newer ones only provide the second one (`${params.TIMEOUT}`).